# SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A record packet with illegal version was received

Tags: svn, error-handling, jenkins

I am getting the following error while doing SVN actions on my Linux machine.

```
svn info https://<my_svn_repo>
```

Error:

> svn: OPTIONS of 'https://': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A record packet with illegal version was received. (https://)**

But using jenkins (only) on the Same server i am able to checkout the code from same repository.
And from my local (windows) system, i am able to do all the activities.

Comment: What does the command 'wget https://<my_svn_repo>' give? Make sure your Linux machine was built with support for SSL.

Comment: The commands were working a day back .. and nothing had changed configuration wise .. but the commands have stopped working

Comment: the Command wget gives below

wget https://<my_svn_repo>
--2012-07-31 14:51:11--  https://<my_svn_repo>
Resolving <repo_server_name>... <Server_IP>
Connecting to <repo_server_name>|<server_IP>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.

Comment: If the Linux machine is a desktop, try using a browser to navigate to the same URL. What do you see?

Comment: its only the command prompt .... we access it using putty ,,